# Crystal Reports - Sum values where another field isn't a certain value

Tags: crystal-reports

I am attempting to create a report using Crystal Reports which is tied to a dataset.  I am using a foxpro connection to retrieve my data.  In the table there is an `hours` field and there is a `transaction code` field as well as a client field, invoice number, and a few others that are pointless in this case.

Using `Crystal Reports` I am trying to get a `summary of the hours` where the `Transaction Code` is not `"NTX"`.

I am not able to modify my query to exclude `"NTX"` because I will still need to get a total of all transactions regardless of the transcode.

A SQL query would be:

```
SELECT Sum(Hours) FROM table WHERE Transaction <> 'NTX'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert a summarized field on fomrula named 'non-NTX hours':

```
// {@ non-NTX hours}
If {table.transation}<>'NTX" Then
  {table.hours}
Else
  0
```

Comment: Thank you.  Sorry for the late response.  I am new to Crystal and I had no idea it was that easy.  All I needed to do was add that formula in the details section and then the summary of that field in my footer and it worked perfectly.  Thanks.